# Do ordinary native English speakers know the meaning of "plasmid"?

Tags: meaning, roots

Plasmid is a biological word, so I guess most people don't know about the word, but I also heard ( I can be wrong ) native English speakers can presume a word's meaning by the roots.

As the roots of Plasmid are "plasma" and "id", where "plasma" can be blood plasma or physical-state plasma (as StoneyB and Andrew point out), while "id" means "shape, form, picture".

So to a native English speaker who see the word for first time, shall he take it "plasma form", "plasma shape" or something else? And does it sound like a cool word to you?

Comment: This is Gk *plas-* + *-ma* + *-id*, not *plas-* + *mid*.

Comment: I think people would be far more likely to link that word to *plasma,* although whether that's blood plasma or physical-state plasma would be interesting. It appears *plasmid* isn't actually related to either thing.

Comment: Why would native speakers necessarily know anything about roots?

Comment: I don't think an "ordinary" English speaker would have any idea what the word meant. An educated person with an interest in words might make a guess at the meaning of an unfamiliar word based on its roots.

Comment: An obscure technical or medical word isolated from context, might be recognizable as being scientific, but to guess at its meaning depends on the word itself. Plasmid, makes me think of the Italian biscuits for infants called *Plasmon* so my first reaction was to associate it with something to do with nutrition or health. Then refer to the nearest English word equivalent that I know, plasma, as Andrew suggested.

Comment: @StoneyB, thanks for correction, question updated.

Comment: Your recent  edit just proved that you yourself didn't know the roots of the word *plasmid*, why would you think the majority of native speakers would?

Comment: Short answer to your question: no, not a clue.  As for plasmoids, I think many people would guess blobbish things from outer space attacking earth.

Comment: @fixer1234 and Mari-Lou, I don't know but heard that thing from my English teacher, I myself am not a native English speaker, but I see your point, actually the majority of native English speakers have no much knowledge about roots, is it right?

Comment: @ab2, thanks for your idea, but why it must attach earth? Does it sound like a bad thing to you?

Comment: @Edward so if the majority of native speakers don't know the meaning a particular word, because "plasmid" *is* a scientific term, you then presume they can't guess the meaning of any unfamiliar word. It doesn't work like that. I could write *sanguineous*, some will recognize its meaning, some will associate it with sanguine, some will have studied biology at High school and probably have had some contact with its derivatives, some speakers will not have the slightest clue, but they'll guess it is an adjective.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, you are right, so my conclusion is most people have no idea what it is, but will very likely associate with a similar word he know, while a few will presume on the roots, and fewer know its meaning.

Comment: I would second @Kate’s comment here. I’ve never heard the word before, but I immediately understood it as _plasma_ + _-id_, i.e., probably referring to something that is plasma-like in form or function.

Comment: To chip in on how actually _understanding_ (some) of the roots may lead to confusion, I know the Greek word _πλάσμα_ as meaning _creature_, which would throw me off the most likely meanings of the word in _English (medical or otherwise scientific)_ usage. I guess a _gollem_ could come to mind as a _plasmid_.

Comment: Speaking as a relative techie, I would recognize the word to the extent of knowing that I haven't an eff what it means.

Comment: A lot of people are going to be familiar with the term as being associated with genetics from the video game Bioshock. So its coolness will be limited by the fact that it's been used previously.

Comment: As others have noted, the word may be considered somewhat obscure. However, online dictionaries, search engines and encyclopedias are often close at hand. May I ask - in your context, what's the significance of whether the general English-speaking population can glean something of the definition of *plasmid* just by looking at the word? For example, are you writing a pamphlet for general distribution and wondering whether to include the definition of *plasmid*?

Comment: If one has played Bioshock one will be familiar with it.

Comment: What is Bioschlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plasmid](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plasmid) does not have a long pedigree:

> First Known Use: 1952

I used this [readability tool](http://www.webpagefx.com/tools/read-able/check.php), and it rated plasmid as follows:

> TEST RESULTS:
>   Your text has an average grade level of about 10. It should be easily understood by 15 to 16 year olds.

Despite this assertion, I did not recognize this word from its biological usage. I may of heard the word in a genetics class that I took in the 1980s and promptly forgotten it.

What about the root word, *plasma*? [Plasma](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plasma) is an ambivalent word, with two biological meanings and two physics meanings (and quartz thrown in for good measure).

> 1 a green faintly translucent quartz
>   2 [New Latin, from Late Latin]
>   a :  the fluid part of blood, lymph, or milk as distinguished from suspended material; especially :  blood plasma
>   b :  the juice that can be expressed from muscle
>   3 protoplasm
>   4  a collection of charged particles (as in the atmospheres of stars or in a metal) containing about equal numbers of positive ions and electrons and exhibiting some properties of a gas but differing from a gas in being a good conductor of electricity and in being affected by a magnetic field
>   5 a display (as a television screen) consisting of discrete cells of plasma sandwiched between two layers of glass and electrodes such that each cell emits light when it receives an electric current

(In contrast, the readability tool rated *plasma* with an average grade level of 7.)

In many schools, they still teach that there are three fundamental states of matter (solid, liquid, gas). But plasma is the fourth state.

> Plasma, from Greek πλάσμα, meaning "anything formed", is one of the four fundamental states of matter, the others being solid, liquid, and gas. ([citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)))

It sounds like you are tending towards the physics meaning. Yes, the word *plasmid* sounds cool. Rather than *plasmid*, I think the alien should take *plasma form* or *plasma-morph* and sandwich himself between two sheets of glass and achieve phosphorescence through continuous bombardment of electrons. You could call him *TV man*.

Comment: Where did you find your two frequency statements? Bottom 20% for plasmid and bottom 40% for plasma?

Comment: @Mitch, click on the M-W link. It gives the popularity rankings. (These rankings may provide a handy guide to the OP's question about whether an English speaker would recognize the word.)

Comment: @rajah9, when you say it is a cool word, do you mean "plasmid" or "plasma"?

Comment: @rajah9 1st impression: Nice! MW has finally added a very important feature of a word to tell you how frequent a word is. 2nd impression: I tried some other words and the number seems... crazy? 'unmitigate' top 30% ? 'heavy' bottom 50% ? Something must be wrong here with what I think 'popular' means. A quantitative metric is a good answer to the OP, but I don't trust these numbers yet. Needs more explanation from MW.

Comment: @rajah9 Just did a look around MW's web pages. For them 'popularity' means the frequency of _lookups_ on their site, not frequency of use in texts in the real world. It really is a popularity contest, the words people are most _curious_ about. So this is a poor metric for recognizability by native speakers.

Comment: @Mitch, Your explanation meshes nicely with my trials of "synecdoche" (top 30%) and "didactic" (top 1%). I'll agree with you that this M-W feature is a poor metric of recognizability (and may in fact be the *opposite*).

Comment: Edited the above to use a readability tool at http://www.webpagefx.com/tools/read-able/check.php instead of M-W. And added that I thought "plasmid" sounded cool.

Comment: @rajah9 Cool, very nice answer, and funny with the TV man part, thank you!